# Is there a word which means whatever you want it to mean? Or has no meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm looking for a word which can be used in any situation to describe something in whatever way you want, i.e it's not a word and just fits in to places..., but is there an actual word which does that?

Comment: "Blah", perhaps?

Comment: _"When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less."_ (from [Lewis Carroll's _The Looking Glass_](http://sabian.org/looking_glass6.php))

Comment: Sounds like the definition of pronouns

Comment: Splunge.  See Monty Python

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4K2e7TTdeMo

Comment: "copasthetic"   "cromulent"  or, sadly,  "it"

Comment: Having read all these interesting answers and comments I feel I should warn you that not everyone will understand all of them, so it depends which part of the world you're in and what you're trying to say. I have never heard *foo*, *bar*, *baz* or *smurf* used in this way. Maybe I just don't get out enough. I would probably use thingy/whatsit/blah/doodah depending on context.

Comment: It's local to Philadelphia, but "jawn" pretty much fits this.

Comment: @IQAndreas: I believe that the title you're referring to is ***Through** the Looking Glass*.

Comment: Heavily related but NOT a duplicate [What colloquial word is used when you don't remember a word ...?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49313/what-colloquial-word-is-used-when-you-dont-remember-a-word-but-you-want-to-use)

Comment: I was going to answer, but then I thought, "Whatever!"

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I like Granny Weatherwax's "Wossname."

Comment: Greenlandic has a root _pi-_ whose meaning is basically “whatever it is we’re talking about and that makes sense in the context”. It is one of the few Greenlandic roots that are both nominal and verbal (thus requiring no suffixing for either use). Highly useful root to have. [It says something about Greenlanders, perhaps, that the original meaning of the root seems to be ‘hunt’.]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo (not a word that takes on arbitrary meaning, but is any part of speech)

Comment: I think the question is somewhat ambiguous.  Most of the answers already given are nouns, but from the way the OP describes the putative word it could possibly be an adjective with vague or unlimited descriptive power - which _"describe[s] something in whatever way you want"_.

Answer (score 69):

> I’m looking for a word which can be used in any situation to describe something in whatever way you want, i.e it’s not a word and just fits in to places, but is there an actual word which does that?

There are quite a few, as a matter of fact. The most popular is **'thingamajig'** with its many variants (thingamabob, thingummy, thingy, etc.), 'whatchamacallit', 'whaddayacallit'.

A useful neologism is '**gizmo**' which should be used only for small, *technological* objects, but can have a wider usage, more or less like 'contraption', 'gadget', 'widget' etc.

The terms 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz' are meaningless, are used in computing by a small circle of adepts. They are used in listing, like letters: "let's take A, B, C"

For people, you probably know the use of 'Tom Dick and Harry', but remember that **'whatsit'** is a *magic word* that can be used for anything, both for people and objects

Comment: +1 Also [*framus*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=framus)

Comment: "Widget" is another one.

Comment: The Irish equivalent to *thingumibob* is *yoke*.

Comment: technically, these are all nouns and can't replace any part of speech.

Comment: @Oldcat the OP asked for a "describing" word, which suggests non-verbs

Comment: But also non nouns.  Those are adjectives and adverbs.

Comment: @Oldcat Some of these can be forced into a different part of speech reasonably well - i.e. "whatchamacallitted" or "whatchamacallitty".  Ambiguous adjectives or adverbs are much less useful than ambiguous nouns, though.  For verbs, you can also say something like "did a thingy".

Comment: The first thing I thought after reading the question was “foo.”

Comment: Do you mean "baz" instead of "faz"? I've never seen the latter. By the way, continuing the list: "qux", "quux", etc.

Comment: Sid at [userfriendly](http://ars.userfriendly.org/cartoons/?id=20080407) uses 'mumble'

Comment: It's "baz", not "faz". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: @DennisWilliamson http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3092

Comment: @TRiG For American's its "new yoke" now

Answer (score 61):

Well, the first word that comes to mind is [**smurf**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs#Language).

It can act as just about any word you want, it can be use as a noun, a verb, an adjective, and the meaning is completely open.

> Can you smurf that for me?
>   Who smurfed my smurfs?
>   What a smurf outfit! You'll attract a lot of smurfs with that!

Comment: I actually, literally, just laughed out loud at this.

Comment: We don't need that smut here. And you smurfing know it!

Comment: This was exactly what I thought of when I read the question. The origin of smurf (schtroumph, actually) was a conversation between the author (Peyo) and a friend; he wanted to ask for the salt, but could not remember the word. So he said "please pass the smurf". Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs

Comment: To me, it seems like it'd be "a smurfy outfit," or "a smurfish outfit."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor — That depends on weather you want to attract smurfs or smurfs... A _smurfy_ outfit would still be acceptable, but a _smurfish_ outfit would be outright smurf! You couldn't pull off a smurfish outfit at any but the smurfiest event.

Comment: @oerkelens +1 Smurfing point!

Comment: +1! Smurf is the best answer. You can line up your lambdas and your X's and all the rest as contenders, but *smurf* smurfs to the head of the smurf, every smurfing time.

Comment: I have never heard the word used liked this, and if someone used in the context I would be totally bemused - and distracted trying to figure out how the conversation related to those little blue cartoon character guys.

Comment: @wim — if you really know the little blue guys, you know how they talk and you would not be so bemused. If you know nothing about the Smurfs, then, yes, it won't make much sense. But that seems a bit obvious... If I do not know what a cow looks like, a description of milking it will also be very bemusing. Then again, if I do not know any of the other words mentioned as alternatives, I would not understand the intention either.

Comment: This is the right answer. But I might be biased by the amount of usage of it I was exposed to when I was little.

Comment: Of smurf, usually the smurf can be smurfed from context.

Comment: I think the word 'smurf' is indeed a word which can be used as replacement of any word. And, an advantage is that the word is quite universal, i.e. a Dutchman, like myself, would probably instantly understand it.

Comment: For those who somehow have remained in the dark wrt smurfness, here is [one reference](http://smurfs.wikia.com/wiki/Smurf_(language)). And here's [googling *smurf talk*](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=smurf+talk).

Comment: In the event that you're speaking with a gamer, I would advise caution: *smurf* has a very precise meaning in competitive gaming. It refers to a player (or account) who is playing in competitive matchmaking while using an account/character that is officially ranked much lower than the player's own abilities. Thus the player is matched against opponents who are less skilled and tends to dominate the game. The player is said to be a *smurf*, and the action is called *smurfing*. I don't know why.

Answer (score 55):

A term which *describes* such words is "***metasyntactic variable***".

The most common metasyntactic variables (in my experience) are "**foo**", "**bar**", and (rarely, because the need for a third placeholder is relatively infrequent) "**baz**". From [Wikipedia's article on metasyntactic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metavariable):

> When you have to invent an arbitrary temporary name for something for the sake of exposition, FOO is usually used. If you need a second one, BAR or BAZ is usually used;

With that said, I'd counsel you not to overdo it, lest you fall into the trap of [Humpty-dumptyism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumptyism#Noun) (*the practice of insisting that a word means whatever one wishes it to*):

> "When ***I*** use a word," Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean- neither more nor less."

From Lewis Carroll's [*Through the Looking Glass*](http://www.fecundity.com/pmagnus/humpty.html)

Comment: Well, there's glory for you.

Comment: Note that foo, bar, and baz are typically used in noun places.  E.g., "I give you this foo."  For a verb, "frob" is often used.  E.g., "You should frob the foo that I gave you."

Comment: @joshuataylor I agree that's the most common usage, if only because nouns occupy the most commonly abstracted category in speech (compare the leading answer's thingamajig, gizmo, whatchamacallit, etc, all very "noun flavored"). But `foo`, `bar`, `baz` do see much wider application than just nouns; in particular, using them for verbs, the *second* most commonly abstracted concept, is almost as common as their use for verbs (for example, as names for functions [verbs] in a programming context). In fact, thy can be used to stand in for **any** part of speech, hence **metasyntactic**: above syntax

Comment: @DanBron Interesting point;  in abstract, I wouldn't hesitate to name a function `foo`, but if I had to talk about it as well, I'd much prefer `frob`.  I'd understand what someone means if they say "then you should foo the bar," but it sounds ungrammatical to me.  Even worse would be "you should foo the frob."

Comment: OK, it's not technically one word, but I nominate "metasyntactic variable" for meaning whatever you want and simultaneously having no (apparent) meaning. ;)

Comment: Another variety is what linguists call "Nonce forms" like _whatchamacallit, doohickey, whozis, frammis,_ etc. They are cardboard models instead of properly-machined words that fit precisely in place and run smoothly; but sometimes a cardboard model will do, especially if you use gestures and don't let the motor run long.

Answer (score 8):

I would start with the word ***blah***. You can replace any bit of speech with "blah, blah, blah." It is often used in a snide way, however, for words that are tedious, or in mockery of another person who won't stop talking.

There are variations as well. I've heard blih, blip, bleh, blipity, and bibity. You can add suffixes as needed too. -ish, -y, and -ed would all work. Actually, ***any amount of humming and hawing while gesturing like an ape can replace any words.*** Too many intentional meaningless words, though, and it will just look like gibberish.

After that the ***wachamacallit's and whosit's*** and so forth can replace any noun, as was already mentioned.

I would like to bring up the curious usage of ***the F-word***, too. It can be used as pretty much any part of speech with nearly any tone, except maybe reverent. Perhaps, with some clever wording, you could replace words with the F-word and your listeners would still understand you.

Comment: What does this mean, "the F-word" ? We are on a site about language & words. Don't be afraid of words.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco There is a time to use words and a time for their euphemisms. I don't want to surprise and upset anybody.

Comment: He means the kind of use as displayed in http://reallifeglobal.com/how-use-word-fuck/ . As they say on that page, if you are going to swear, you should have a high degree of awareness as to what you are communicating and the effect it has on people around you.

Comment: I think the F-word can be used reverently. It just depends on context and attitude.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco the F-word means whatever you want it to mean - so it is perfect.  It could even mean "fuck" if you wanted it to.

Comment: @emory Exactly the point I was trying to make, but some other users are hung up on me saying "F-word" instead of spelling it out.

Answer (score 6):

Really for the extreme flexibility you're looking for the closest word or phrase that I'm aware of that is in common use is "you know" which can be combined with "what", "who", "what I'm talking about" or a small description for claity.

So yesterday I went to the you know where we usually go and, well, you know who showed up, and he's wearing his typical you know, like, thinks he's so stylish and he's not, and then he pulls out one of those you know new phones and he's acting all like he's so you know, like just because he's got a phone he can just be such a you know what.

Answer (score 4):

If we are going with fictional words, Og wins.

Whereas Smurf is always a positive word, and Marklar from South Park is always a noun, Og from *The Secret World of Og* is every word, except for (according to [this random wiki entry](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Marklar)) mathematical operators.

I have not read the book so I do not know if the part about mathematical operators is accurate. According to [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_World_of_Og) the inhabitants only know one word: "Og!" (EDIT: I suppose operators can exist as such without their being words: Og + Og = Og. But if this is the case, then said word (Og) does not, as the OP asks, stand in for "whatever you want it to mean" unless, in Og, you can express + as a word (plus = Og)).

Comment: Plus one for Marklar...

Comment: "Hodor!" "Pikachu!" "I am Groot!"

Comment: Oh, those are good, didn't even think of them. I wouldn't count Pikachu, he often uses pikaaaa... for angry/disappointed phrases and Pika Pika! for excited/happy phrases and... well I guess that dichotomy is the entirety of his emotional range in the show.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in Hawaii, Da Kine is exactly what you're looking for.

It is used as a noun, verb, adjective, adverb.

But do note, Da Kine is pidgin English.

Comment: What does your note mean ? Da Kine comes from english ?

Comment: Why Da Kine has capital letters ?

Comment: He means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_pidgin

Comment: And from Melanesian Pidgin (Tok Pisin) the word 'samting'. It looks like 'something' but is not. Usage is much broader and it may be used in place of a noun or verb. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tok_Pisin

Answer (score 4):

I immediately thought of plain old

### Thing

- Look at that **thing**
- I have one of those **things**
- There's a **thing** that fixes that
- That **thing** is on the desk

Answer (score 3):

You used some in your question: "something," "whatever," etc., are placeholder words to allow *whatever* or *something* to be inserted at the readers discretion.

But actually, the first word that came to my mind was...

> **Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious**

Which, as [Wikipedia notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious) "According to the film [*Mary Poppins* (1964), which spawned the popular and exact term here, though variations existed as far back as 1931 according to the article], it is defined as "'something to say when you have nothing to say'".

It is in fact in the [Oxford English Dictionary (login required)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194228), defined as "A nonsense word" (i.e. **a word that *has no meaning***), though notes that in practice, used by children, "typically expressing excited approbation: fantastic, fabulous."

The word is in fact an adjective, and since it has no meaning, it therefore meets the request that it "describe something in whatever way you want" (though again, in usage it often has an idea of good connotations of "approval"—so [the Random House definition on dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious)—since [the song](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious) notes positive aspects experienced by the use of the word).

Comment: The sound of it is something quite atrocious.

Comment: @glenatron: Indeed, though not all agree with [Mary Poppin's and crew's assessment of the word](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious), as [this article](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-17279039) notes "lexicographer Susie Dent" saying it is "'beautifully crafted in its beat so that once you learn it, it is hard to forget,'" and "Matt Wolf, a theatre critic" that "'There's something about the polysyllabic nature of it that makes you want to move to it. It makes language exciting, it makes words fun.'"  But for the OP, it truly is _defined_ as having _no meaning_.

Comment: For "something to say when you have nothing to say", just listen to a politician.  Or a corporate exec.  (Or, of course, an advertisement of any sort.)

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat English-sounding one that's common in Terry Pratchett novels is **wossname**.

e.g.:

> That's a referential wossname. A gerund. Could be a gerund.
>
> He had a cut all the way across his wossname.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the word **Placeholder** could mean anything but it might be limited to just nouns.

**Blank** is my second choice.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a word for an indefinite number, there are "umpteen" and "zillion" (for a very big number). Perhaps "*n*" doesn't count as word, but its ordinal form "nth" is quite often seen, especially in the phrase "to the nth degree". See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers

Answer (score -4):

I think that the word `that` might fit the bill. You can use it as a noun:

```
I want that.
```

Or disguise it as an adjective:

```
He looked like that.
```

Or even take the place of an adjective.

```
He was pretty.
Yes, sir, that he was.
```

As commented below, its meaning usually refers to an antecedent, either verbal or non-verbal, but there are plenty of examples in English where the anaphora is left open:

```
Just like that, he disappeared.
It's too expensive, and probably out-of-date at that.
```

([ref](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/at-that)). Therefore the antecedent can be left as ambiguous as desired. Add to it that the word `that` has many [other uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That) in English:

```
He said that it was time.
```

I find the ambiguity fits the bill of "a word which can be used in any situation to describe something in whatever way you want". Let us see:

```
We have to agree that Peter was that.
She was doing that. Yes, that. I don't have to say what that is.
```

And that is that.

Comment: *That* is a pronoun, so it's true that it's job is to take the place of a noun, but it's always used with an antecedent or at least some sort of (possibly nonverbal) indication of what the speaker intends to refer to. In this question the OP seems to be asking for a placeholder word that can be used without indicating its meaning. Also, *that* in *He looked like that* is still a pronoun, not an adjective.

Comment: The question said "it's not a word and just fits in to places". I will try to improve on the answer.

Comment: Followed by: *but is there an actual word which does that?* The question could use some work.

Comment: The word "that" has nothing to do with a particle.

Comment: Removed the bit about a particle, replaced by "many uses".

Comment: I do not see any anaphora here.

Comment: Consider the phrase "he disappeared just like that": it is an anaphora ("like that"), but there is no antecedent. In oral form there can be a gesture that suggests a magic trick, but in written form the antecedent is gone and there is only an "open" anaphora.

Answer (score -5):

*Hodor*. The only word uttered by character known by that name in George R. R. Martin's series of novels *A Song of Ice and Fire*. See http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hodor, http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hodor, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxjw-w-V5k4.

Answer (score -7):

**Dude**,
an expression of shock, approval, sympathy, or other strong feeling:
Dude! That's one expensive sandwich!

-[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: I think that **dude** means **a guy**. I would not say "Dude !" to a girl.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco saying it to a girl is sometimes okay. As an exclamation; not like "hey dude".

Comment: No exclamation exists that I cannot replace with dude using the proper tone.

Comment: I challenge you to find the proper tone to say _dude_ to replace something like _G*dawfullF***ingSonOfAB**ch_! after hitting your finger instead of a nail with that slightly overweight hammer...

Comment: Touche, applicable for when it doesn't hurt yet, but you know it will very soon and take forever to heal. Useful for when you do rehab in a working office and shouting expletives is frowned upon. @oerkelens