# Correct usage of *which* and *that*

Tags: word-usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, which-that, is-it-a-rule

I keep seeing written usage of *which* in cases where the writer clearly intends it to be restrictive. For example:

- "[Is there a word which means whatever you want it to mean? Or has no meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192145/is-there-a-word-which-means-whatever-you-want-it-to-mean-or-has-no-meaning)"
- "[It will only contain elements from the input sequence which pass the predicate.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/)" (And other occurrences on the same page and in the same blog.)

I have been counting these as errors because it is my understanding that *that* is restrictive, and *which* is not.

Do I have this right?

Comment: Of the two listed "duplicates", only one actually is. The other is too specific to be a duplicate of this more general question. And yes, I searched many different ways to try to find the answer on the site before asking...